# Month picker issue in JSF

Tags: jsf, datepicker, richfaces, monthcalendar

I have month picker in JSF .It shows only month and year.Its not working properly .

Isssue:

1. I am unable to slect the current month .
2. Some times the selected value not assigned to the  backend (bean)
   variable.

Code:

```
<rich:calendar id="frommonth" status="rule"
               value="#{AddressBean.monthSearch}"
               locale="US" datePattern="MMM.yyyy"
               oncurrentdateselected="event.rich.component.selectDate(event.rich.date)"
               showWeekDaysBar="false" showFooter="true"
               popup="true" styleClass="special"
               style="width:200px" showApplyButton="true" 
               inputClass="calenderFld">                            
</rich:calendar>
```

style:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .special tr[id] {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Can anyone help me on this issue ? Or guide me If there any other way to obtain the month and year picker in JSF.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the current month, there is a **Today** button in the calendar footer (since `showFooter="true"`) that you can use to set the calendar to current month.

As for the value that is not set, i am not sure what is your case exactly, check is there is any validation error in your page that does not let values be set in the bean

Comment: @dimcookiew Is it possible to change the footer string from "Today" to  CurrentMonth

Comment: You shoud define in your resource bundle the value for `RICH_CALENDAR_TODAY_LABEL` constant. For example `RICH_CALENDAR_TODAY_LABEL=Current Month`